# React Formik : how to use custom onChange and onBlur

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I'm starting out with the [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) library for react, and I can't figure out the usage of the props handleChange and handleBlur.

According to [the docs](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik#handleblur-e-any--void), handleBlur can be set as a prop on a `<Formik/>`, and then has to be passed manually down to the `<input/>`.

I've tried that, with no success :
(I'm keeping the code about handleBlur for more clarity)

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field, Form } from "formik";
import { indexBy, map, compose } from "ramda";
import { withReducer } from "recompose";

const MyInput = ({ field, form, handleBlur, ...rest }) =>
  <div>
    <input {...field} onBlur={handleBlur} {...rest} />
    {form.errors[field.name] &&
      form.touched[field.name] &&
      <div>
        {form.errors[field.name]}
      </div>}
  </div>;

const indexById = indexBy(o => o.id);
const mapToEmpty = map(() => "");

const EmailsForm = ({ fieldsList }) =>
  <Formik
    initialValues={compose(mapToEmpty, indexById)(fieldsList)}
    validate={values => {
      // console.log("validate", { values });
      const errors = { values };
      return errors;
    }}
    onSubmit={values => {
      console.log("onSubmit", { values });
    }}
    handleBlur={e => console.log("bluuuuurr", { e })}
    render={({ isSubmitting, handleBlur }) =>
      <Form>
        <Field
          component={MyInput}
          name="email"
          type="email"
          handleBlur={handleBlur}
        />
        <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </Form>}
  />;
```

What is wrong with this approach ?
How are handleBlur and handleChange actually supposed to be used ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You'll need to remove the first `handleBlur` from `Formik` as blur event is only valid on the field level and do something like the following in your Field element:

```
<Field
    component={MyInput}
    name="email"
    type="email"
    onBlur={e => {
        // call the built-in handleBur
        handleBlur(e)
        // and do something about e
        let someValue = e.currentTarget.value
        ...
    }}
/>
```

See https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/157

Comment: This is ok as long as you don't need to manipulate the value. In my case, I wanted to reformat field's value inside the custom blur handler which triggers issues with validation as `setFieldValue()` is not async. See https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/529

Comment: I think that's a separate Formik issue where you can't get the updated field value right after you do a `setFieldValue()` on the same field without some workarounds. I was one of the participants in that discussion.

Answer (score 1):

According to the above mention question code, you just need to change only one thing i.e. **onBlurCapture**={handleBlur}

which works on html input element. onBlur, onFocusOut are not supported by the react. However, I got the same issue and finally resolved with  component in react-formik with render props.

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck on a related issue for hours, and this helped me get to the solution.

Comment: Its my pleasure Ash West, Thanks for reply. It motivate me.

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem using onChange method, which i think do not exist in formik props.

so i used the onSubmit method as it's available in the formik props which gives us the fields values and then passed that values to the concern function like so ...

```
<Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={signInSchema}
          onSubmit={(values) => {
            registerWithApp(values);
            console.log(values);
          }}
        >
```

and there you can use, i simply updated the state and passed it to axios like so...

```
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const registerWithApp = (data) => {
    const { name, email, password } = data;
    setUser({
      name:name,
      email:email,
      password:password
    })
   
    if (name && email && password) {
      axios.post("http://localhost:5000/signup", user)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    }
    else {
      alert("invalid input")
    };
  }
```

and its working ...
I hope its helps you.