# withFormik(): How to use handleChange

Tags: reactjs, formik

**Current platform:  NodeJS (minimal), client-side React w/Redux, Formik, Yup.**

Given the following example code (not including the entire React Component code since it's irrelevant to the question):

```
class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    // (...)

    render () {
        <Form>
            <Field name="email" type="email" />
            <Field name="password" type="password" />
            <Field 
                name="myCheckbox" 
                type="checkbox"
                checked={this.props.values.myCheckbox}
                onChange={  ??????????  } />
        </Form>
    }
}

const handleFormSubmission = (values, { resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(values);
};

const handleFormChange = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    console.log('changed');
};

const MyFormik = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues ({ email, password, myCheckbox }) {
        return {
            email: email || '',
            password: password || '',
            myCheckbox: myCheckbox || false
       }
    },
    validationSchema: (...Yup schema here...),
    handleSubmit (values, bag) { return handleFormSubmission(values, bag); }
})(RegisterPage);

export default connect()(MyFormik);
```

...**how can I use the handleChange method**?  I need to persist the original one (the one from Formik) while adding code that handles that checkbox change.  There's some component behavior that depends on the checked value of that checkbox.

Please notice that I'm not passing the onChange prop to email or password, since there is no extra behavior to code for on those.  The checkbox is the one that will have special behavior.

Comment: not clear what you're asking. Have you tried something? The custom onChange for the Field overlaps the one from `Formik`?

Comment: withFormik() takes care of the need to explicitly pass an onChange handler to every input inside the form.  That is why email and password are not being passed the onChange prop:  withFormik takes care of the change handling for you.  However, when you DO need to perform some task in the change event, you can specify which handler to call, but I don't know how to specify it. withFormik's configuration object only supports handleSubmit. So I need to know how to pass in the handleChange so that I can persist formik's handling and add custom code to it.

Comment: Had you tried to just put a handler inside the `onChange`? take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466920/react-formik-how-to-use-custom-onchange-and-onblur

Comment: Ohhhh....nope I haven't tried passing an arrow function in the onChange prop...ok, I'll try that and I'll come back and share the result.

Comment: Yep!! that did it!! I'll post an answer below but I'll leave it open just in case somebody comes up with something even better ;-) thanks man!

Comment: That's the solution for your problem. If you want a custom handler, you just need to use it! As far as I know, there is no other solution

Answer (score 11):

You can declare a handler for the checkbox, and use it! Using the native handler of Formkit, and your custom handler.

```
class RegisterPage extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
   // (...)
   handleCheckBox: (e) => {
       // do whatever you want to the value
   }
   render () {
       <Form>
           <Field name="email" type="email" />
           <Field name="password" type="password" />
           <Field 
               name="myCheckbox" 
               type="checkbox"
               checked={this.props.values.myCheckbox}
               onChange={(e) => {this.props.handleChange(e); this.handleCheckBox(e)}} />
       </Form>
   }
}
```

Comment: suggested edit:  the handleCheckBox function should call this.props.handleChange(e) first and then the additional code should be performed.  That way formik stays linked to the checkbox.

Comment: Ok...It does work, but has it setbacks.  Here's the deal: (1) The call to this.props.handleChange is mandatory. Otherwise Formik will not update the form values. (2) Unfortunately this.props.handleChange is asynchronous with no Promise being returned and no callback arguments supported. This means that Formik is maintaining its own state and whatever you code after that call is too fast for formik to be able to update the checkbox's state before you can use its new value.  So the final solution has to be one based on extending Formik's change function so that it can have time to update the val

Comment: @Arnie How'd you do your final solution of extending Formik's change function? I've been confused about this and couldn't come up w/ a way of asking my question and then found your question here.

Comment: @sabliao I apologize for the late reply.  Unfortunately I never found a final solution to this issue. I ended up solving my situation in another way:  by simply not using that checkbox as part of my implementation. I chose to satisfy the use of that checkbox with a different solution and moved on.  However, I did toy around with async/await in the function wrapper, so that I could persist formik's function and then resolve something but that didn't look elegant at all, and had issues of its own.

Comment: You can't set a custom value with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if you want to handle checkbox

```js
onChange={(e, event) => {
   handleChange({ ...event, target: { name: 'isDeleted', value: e } })
}}
```