# How to handle Formik's `handleChange` prop?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I get it that `Field` has an `onChange` attribute where you can pass the own Formik `onChange` prop from here: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#handlechange-e-reactchangeevent-any-void.

However, I am struggling to understand where these `value[key]` is passed, so I can handle the data passed in the form. Found in [withFormik(): How to use handleChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159477/withformik-how-to-use-handlechange) that I can pass two callbacks to Formik's `onChange` prop, but I wonder if there is a better way to handle this.

**edit after comments from folks that replied, thanks for that:**

My code using these 2 callbacks in the onChange prop in `Field`:

```
export default function FormikForm() {
  const onSubmitHandler = (formValues, actions) => {
    console.log(formValues);
    console.log(actions);
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>This is the Formik Form</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          name: "",
          email: "",
          age: ""
        }}
        onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}
        render={props => {
          return (
            <Form>
              <label>
                Name
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="name"
                  onChange={e => {props.handleChange(e); onChangeHandler(e)}}
                />
              </label>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing as in `onSubmitHandler`, where Formik automagically outputs the value of the input without having to call these 2 functions in the `onChange`?

Thanks

Comment: not clear on your question, what are you struggling at exactly, where did you come up with `value[key]` any code example that you can post here on which you want to get things cleared? Also you are writing your question like BAs, try to write it as a sentence, its ok to post a link inline instead of writing [0] which when I read it as a developer seemed like an array `prop[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Every field component receives a [field prop](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field) which has a `value` prop containing the value for that field, as well as a `form` prop containing helper methods that you can use to set the value.  I'd need to see the structure of your code to give specific suggestions on how to implement what you want, but you can emulate the default functionality by calling `form.setFieldValue(field.name, field.value)`.  In addition, the `field` prop has this handler built in by default in the `field.onChange` prop.

Comment: Thanks @rutherford, added my snippet of code, hope it is more clear now.