# Why is OnChange not working when used in Formik?

Tags: html, reactjs, formik

I am trying to use Formik in React for a dummy app. I am not being able to type anything in either of the input boxes if I give value as a prop. On the other hand, if I skip the value props, then I can type in the boxes but the same is not reflected as the value while submitting.

Here's the code:

```
export default class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{ fname: "", lname: "" }}
                        onSubmit={(values) => {
                            alert(values.fname);
                        }}
                        render={({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                               <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" onChange={handleChange} value={values.fname} />
                               <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" onChange={handleChange} value={values.lname} />
                               <button type="submit>ADD<button/>
                            </form>
                        )}
                    />
        );
    }
```

}

I may be very wrong here and might be over-looking a minor error, but any help/suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Try to put what you wrote inside the render prop as child of the <Formik> Element in the same way is in the example: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview

Comment: Where does handleChange come from? I think you're missing props?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
export default class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ fname: "", lname: "" }}
        onSubmit={ (values) => alert(values.fname) }
      >
      { props => (
        <React.Fragment>                     
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" onChangeText={props.handleChange('fname')} />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" onChangeText={props.handleChange('lname')} />
          <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      </Formik>
    )
  }
}
```

Hi mate can you please try this?

Comment: Hey @BOna, yes it did solve the issue. Can you help me with one more thing, suppose I want to write my own handleChane function so that I can mask the values or do anything with the value before it is stored in the Formik state. Can it be done? How?

Comment: Hi there is an answer in this topic: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466920/react-formik-how-to-use-custom-onchange-and-onblur] May i ask why you want to modify your values before stocking it in Formik 's initial values?  If it is for validation (password length, ...) it is not how to do it and you might want to look after Yup.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue but don't get how to fix it. Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689720/onchange-on-textinput-not-working-inside-formik

Answer (score 3):

Mine was also not working, I gave id prop in my TextField and now it works

```js
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },

    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      // onLogin(values.username, values.password);
    },
  });

<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            value={formik.values.username}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            id="username"
            name="username"
            variant="outlined"
            style={TextField1style}
            placeholder="Enter username"
            fullWidth
            required
            //.
            // .
           // .
            // other code
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQns7.png)

Comment: Yours is definitely the right answer setting the id attribute did the job

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for this weird behavior is putting your component inside a function and sending the props as function parameters instead of using a functional component with props as parameters.

When a component is inside a function you lose react component lifecycle and the parameters will not refresh even when its values change.

Make sure your form elements are properly configured as react elements.

Comment: i don't get it i see how you call formik.handleChange but where you wire it to a function to do anything

Answer (score 0):

instead of "fname" and "lname"
pass them as
{values.fname} and {values.lname}...if the names are not correctly passed formik doesnot know which field to change.